# task<AuthResult> task is not successfull in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to make sign up page in firebase database i have done all the implementation regarding firebase but

task is not successfull in this case i don't know how but i

t does not go to if condition it only goes to else condition

```
  if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            user User=new user(name,profession,email,password);
                            String id=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            database.getReference().child("users").child(id).setValue(User);
                            Toast.makeText(signup.this, "signup successfully",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(signup.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

it does not go to if condition it only goes to else condition

signup.java

```
package com.example.instagram;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.instagram.databinding.ActivitySignupBinding;
import com.example.instagram.model.user;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView signup;
    Button signupbtn;
    ActivitySignupBinding binding;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        binding=ActivitySignupBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        signup=findViewById(R.id.signup);
        signupbtn=findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        String email=binding.email.getText().toString();
        String password=binding.pwd.getText().toString();
        String name=binding.Name.getText().toString();
        String profession=binding.profession.getText().toString();

        signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email=binding.email.getText().toString();
                String password=binding.pwd.getText().toString();
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).
                        addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            user User=new user(name,profession,email,password);
                            String id=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            database.getReference().child("users").child(id).setValue(User);
                            Toast.makeText(signup.this, "signup successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(signup.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(signup.this,loginpage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

signup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".loginpage">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Instagram"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="223dp"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/instagram" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to social world"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/profession"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="profession"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profession" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwd"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:background="@drawable/inputbg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.063" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signupbtn"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="sign up"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pwd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Already have a account? "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/signup"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signupbtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.859" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="63dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="Log In!"
        android:textColor="#F10606"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signupbtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.86" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle(module level)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.instagram"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.9'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.hardik.hsdp:scalablesize-android:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.MrNouri:DynamicSizes:1.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

help to out be get if condition runs successfully

Comment: Have  you tried to use `Toast.makeText(signup.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`? What the message that you get?

Comment: @AlexMamo i have got failed message    please help this out to figured it out

Comment: What is the "failed message"?

Comment: thanks for replying i have solve error successfully       Appreciated  thank you for work efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have not started `Authentication`

1. Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Open your project
3. Open `Authentication` tab under **Build**
4. Click 'Get Started'
5. Select 'Email/password' as you provider.
6. Enable & Save it..

Now try to create account from your android application.

[image]

Comment: i have already done that  but i donot know why task is not successful please help me out with this

Comment: Can you show the error message in your `else` case. Log.d("MyTag", task.getException().getMessage());

Comment: thanks a lot bro by writing this Log.d("MyTag", task.getException().getMessage()); code it helps me to find out the actual error which solves my Problem Appricated

Comment: If you find it helpful, kindly accept it too